# How to prevent the long text beyond the boundary of the border in XSL-fo?

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to display a long text in xsl-fo. I have used wrap-option also but it did not work and still overflowing occurs for the text. Kindly suggest any idea for this.
The code is-
`<fo:block font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap">
<xsl:value-of select="$advertNotes"/> 
</fo:block>`

Comment: `wrap-option="no-wrap"` forces the text to not break.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#wrap-option.  What happens when you don't have `wrap-option="no-wrap"`?

Answer (score 0):

`wrap-option="wrap"`

Allows the text to wrap. But the default of not setting wrap-option to anything should allow wrapping by default. So you must have some code with "no-wrap" if the text is running off the page.